# XML, DTD file missing information

Tags: xml, dtd

I need some help, making sure I understand this and doing it right.

The element rit

1.1. The element rit has an attribute version that must have the value 1.0

1.2. The element rit has a required attribute date that has a text representing the date of feed.

1.3. The element rit can have 0 or more feed elements

1.4. The element rit’s last element is a required doc-copyright element. The copyright statement for your company.

```
<!ELEMENT rit (version, date, feed*, doc-copyright) >

<!ATTLIST ret version CDATA #FIXED "1.0">

<!ATTLIST ret date CDATA #REQUIRED >
```

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry but nobody is going to try to read and digest all that.

Comment: I don't think this question is overly broad and it seems to have all the details necessary, but it might be better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `version` and `date` are attributes, they shouldn't be in the content model of the `rit` element declaration (remove them from `(version, date, feed*, doc-copyright)`).

Don't forget to add element declarations for the `date` and `doc-copyright` elements.

Having multiple `ATTLIST` declarations for an element is ok, but in my opinion it's easier to read and maintain a single `ATTLIST` for an element.

Example of changes...

```
<!ELEMENT rit (feed*, doc-copyright)>

<!ATTLIST ret 
          version CDATA #FIXED    "1.0"
          date    CDATA #REQUIRED     >

<!ELEMENT  feed (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT  doc-copyright (#PCDATA)>
```

Comment: @Micheal - You're very welcome. Please consider accepting this answer by clicking on the checkmark to the left of it.